# How to find the exponent of 2 in an integer in Java?

Tags: java, math, exponential

I want to find the power of 2 that any integer contains. Like  **12 = 2*2*3** so answer should come as **2**, **28 = 2*2*7** so answer should come as **2** and so on.

`int powerOf2InNumber = (int)Math.floor(Math.log(number) / Math.log(2));`

I tried the above code but in cases like 28,26,10 etc i'm getting wrong answer.

Comment: You specifically want to find how many times 2 divides it _exactly_.  The logarithm won't be involved there.

Comment: You should try it with a counter, a `while` loop and the modulo operator

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a handy built-in function,

```
int powersOf2 = Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros(number);
```

Comment: It might be worth mentioning for the uninitiated that this is the number of trailing zeroes of a binary string of the number and not the decimal number.  Of course there's always the JavaDoc.

Comment: Is there something similar for any power or just power of 2? for example if i want to know 45 is how many power of 3?

Comment: @ccot you could use the same thing but for powers of 4, 8, 16 etc by dividing the result of `numberOfTrailingZeros` by 2, 3, 4 etc. But there is nothing similar for powers of 3. Some of the other answers can be generalized to 3 and 5 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
int check = 28;
int count = 0;
while(check % 2 == 0) {
    check /= 2;
    count++;
}
```

Check ends up as the other factor. I.e the 7 in 2 * 2 * 7. Count is your answer.

Answer (score 0):

What I think you're asking is: the number of times 2 goes into a number?

```java
int countPowerOfTwo(int number) {
  int count = 0;
  while (abs(number) > 0) {
    if (number % 2 != 0) {
      return count;
    }
    count++;
    number = number / 2;
  }
  return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way, imo, has already been provided using `Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros`.  It is taken from **Hacker's Delight** which is an excellent book and worth the price.  Another method is as follows:

```
int b = 32*75;
int powerOf2 = BitSet.valueOf(new long[]{b}).nextSetBit(0);
System.out.println(powerOf2);
```

Prints

```
5
```

Note: For completeness you weren't far off in your attempt and logarithms can be used along with some basic bit manipulation.  So you can do the following:

```
int number = 32*75;
int powerOf2 = (int)(Math.log(number & -number)/Math.log(2))
```